# MySQL INNER JOIN select only one row from first table if all leads active = 0 and primary_email = Yes in second table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have two tables. 
I want to join them in a way that only one record in the leads table if leads_details table all lead_id active = 0 and primary = Yes.

table Lead:

```
    -------------
    | id | name |
    -------------
    | 1  | abc1 |
    | 2  | abc2 |
    | 3  | abc3 |
    | 4  | abc4 |
    | 5  | abc5 |
    -------------
```

table LeadsDetails:

```
    --------------------------------------
    | id | lead_id | active | primary_email
    --------------------------------------
    | 1  | 1       | 1       |Yes         |
    | 2  | 1       | 0       |NO          |
    | 3  | 2       | 0       |Yes         |
    | 4  | 3       | 1       |Yes         |
    | 5  | 4       | 0       |Yes         |
    | 6  | 5       | 1       |NO          |
    -------------------------------------
```

expected output:

```
    --------------
    | id | name   |
    --------------
    | 1  | abc2   |
    | 2  | abc4   |
    --------------

SELECT `Lead`.`id`, `Lead`.`name`, `Lead`.`unsubscribe` 
FROM `leads` AS `Lead` inner JOIN `LeadsDetails` AS `LeadsDetails` 
ON (`LeadsDetails`.`lead_id` = `Lead`.`id`) 
WHERE `LeadsDetails`.`primary_email` = 'Yes' AND `LeadsDetails`.`active` = 0
```

Comment: I want to show lead in case primary_email = "Yes" and active = 0 for all same lead_id

Comment: I guess what you want is that if there are more than one results for your query written in expected output for same lead id, then it should return only one lead id.
ex. for lead id 2, there are 2 entries in lead details table with active = 0 and primary email = yes, then instead of returning two records, you want only one record, am i right?
I am asking this because your question is not clear to me.

Comment: @TusharBhaware you are right , i am getting ore than one results, i want to show only 1 lead in case if all same lead_id active = 0 and if any should be `primary_email` = 'Yes'

Comment: Is the combination `lead_id, active=0, primary_email='Yes'` unique in LeadsDeatils table?

Answer (score 2):

You require group by attribute

```
 SELECT `Lead`.`id`, `Lead`.`name`, `Lead`.`unsubscribe` 
FROM `leads` AS `Lead` inner JOIN `LeadsDetails` AS `LeadsDetails` 
ON (`LeadsDetails`.`lead_id` = `Lead`.`id`) 
WHERE `LeadsDetails`.`primary_email` = 'Yes' AND `LeadsDetails`.`active` = 0
GROUP BY lead.id
```